# Не удается копирование столбца из одного dataframe в другой

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn

Мне нужно скопировать в датасет с масштабированными данными ID пользователей.
Или же можно как-то отмасштабировать, игнорируя столбец ID?

```
RFM_scaled = regular_RFM.copy()
RFM_scaled['Recency'] = RFM_scaled['Recency'].dt.days

RFM_scaled = StandartScaler().fit_transform(RFM_scaled.drop(columns='id'))
RFM_scaled = pd.DataFrame(RFM_scaled)
RFM_scaled.columns = ['Recency','Frequency','Monetary value']

RFM_scaled['id'] = regular_RFM['id'].copy()
RFM_scaled.head()
```

В выводе столбец id почему-то NaN

Comment: Ну, начнем с того, что будем править ваши синтаксические ошибки. Нет такого класса "StandartScaler()",  а есть класс "StandardScaler()". Интересно, как же вы при этом выяснили, какие значения в вашем столбце 'id' ?

Comment: И не `.dt.days`, а `.dt.day`. Я попробовал на искусственных данных, всё работает вообще-то.

Comment: У меня Standard, просто было импортировано как ss, поэтому я заменил здесь,чтобы было понятнее, но получилось с ошибкой. А вот насчёт day интересно, вроде ошибок не было, спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помимо уже отмеченных ошибок с `StandartScaler` вместо `StandardScaler` и `days` вместо `day`, основная проблема у вас в том, что вы делаете новый датафрейм и у него индексы сбрасываются, а при копировании `Series` индексы учитываются, поэтому когда вы копируете колонку `id` из одного датафрейма в другой у вас индексы не совпадают. Я так понимаю, что в `regular_RFM` индексы уже не с нуля и подряд, вы что-то с ним делали, поэтому в итоге такой эффект. Починить это можно, взяв в новый датафрейм индексы от старого. Это можно сделать несколькими способами, в частности можно указать индексы при создании нового датафрейма:

```py
RFM_scaled = pd.DataFrame(RFM_scaled, index=regular_RFM.index)
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Если кто-то ещё будет экспериментировать с этим вопросом, то вот код для генерации данных, воспроизводящих проблему:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

regular_RFM = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100,4)), 
    columns = ['id', 'Recency','Frequency','Monetary value'],
    index = range(1000, 1100))
regular_RFM['Recency'] = pd.date_range('2022-02-24', '2022-06-03')
```

P.S. Да, и постарайтесь избегать переиспользования одних и тех же переменных для разных сущностей, это очень запутывает. Да, это экономит память, но это запутывает того, кто читает код. У вас `RFM_scaled` - это и отмасштабированные данные и позже датафрейм с этими данными.

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!